# How do you create a sharable custom url depending on user selected options

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have seen websites that create a sharable link that is generated depending on what options the user chooses but I'm not really sure how they're implemented (or what this process is called).

e.g. [this](http://ffxivrotations.com/) website has a share button at the bottom that creates a sharable link for a given selection.

Comment: they either create entry in db with the selection, generate a link for it. Next time they look it up in db, when this link is accessed. You can also encode selection into the link itself, and parse it later when it is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a rudimental but easy solution. Add a URL Parameter to the button link and redirect on click depending on the parameter.